# Create row ids for dataframes based on contents of rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

**Question:** What is the best way to create dataframe row ids based on the contents of the rows?

I have two dataframes called A and B. I'm looking for a smart way to create ids for the rows in both the dataframes. I know there are [many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085624/pandas-create-foreign-id-column-based-on-name-column) to create foreign ids for dataframes. What I would like however, is to have a method that will create the exact same id for two rows if the rows are identical. That is, if the dataframes A and B look like this:

```
         A
22|'John' |'Smith'
42|'Anne' |'Baker'
22|'John' |'Smith'
46|'Peter'|'Jackson'

         B
27|'Jack' |'Griffin'
52|'Sarah'|'Portman'
22|'John' |'Smith'
46|'Peter'|'Jackson'
```

If would like to be able to create ids like this:

```
          A
id         
98  |22|'John' |'Smith'
746 |42|'Anne' |'Baker'
98  |22|'John' |'Smith'
56  |46|'Peter'|'Jackson'

          B
id         
478 | 27 | 'Jack'  | 'Griffin'
644 | 52 | 'Sarah' | 'Portman'
98  | 22 | 'John'  | 'Smith'
56  | 46 | 'Peter' | 'Jackson'
```

Furthermore, I want to be able to create similar ids for a new dataframe in the future.

I think I can do so by creating a new 'id' column in the dataframes and setting that new column to the values in the other columns, but I don't think this is very elegant. If the number of columns in a dataframe is large or if the cells contain certain datatypes (floats with a lot of decimal numbers for example) the ids will be very long.

Comment: Why does in the same DataFrame the row  22 | 'John'  | 'Smith' does not produce the same row id?

Comment: @gonzalomr My bad, thanks!